# Problem with Jupyter notebook and to reinstalll anaconda?

Tags: installation, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, kernel, ipython

How get permission to install anaconda windows 11??

[image]

This problems appear when a was reisntalling anacaconda. I had to unisntall because my jupyter notebook giving the error:
"KernelRestarter: restart failed"
and
"A connection to the notebook server could not be established. The notebook will continue trying to reconnect. Check your network connection or notebook server configuration."

I fallowed some tutorials and they recommend to reinstall the packages and Anaconda, but the error in print appeared.

I want to use jupytert notebook and annacoda

Answer (score 0):

Run the anaconda installer as administrator. 
It ensures that it has the necessary permissions to write to the installation directory.
It may resolve the permission related issue.

- right click on anaconda installer(.exe) file
- select `run as administrator`